# parentNode.remove() not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

First of all, I'm very new with all that JavaScript stuff. I'm using parentNode.remove() to close a modal box on my site. Works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but nothing in IE (8-9-10-11...).

The link that I use to close the box looks like this:

```
<a onClick="parentNode.remove()" class="close">X</a>
```

Is there a way that I can tweak my onclick to work in Internet Explorer?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe try `this.parentNode.remove()`

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but it still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove();` is a jQuery method. Are you using jQuery?  If so, you could do: `$(this).parent().remove();`.

I don't know if this is just an example, but I would recommend creating a single function instead of adding individually.

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent.remove();
});
```

Comment: There's actually a [DOM method `remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove), which isn't supported in IE (and is why the original code works in Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: @Matt Brennan I knew there was a `remove()` for a `<select>` but didn't know about a generic for FF/Chrome. Thanks for the tip!